# Can I use a Pi as a ethernet switch as well as run something else on it?

Tags: switches

I am thinking of using a pi beside the front gate with some custom software to translate rest calls to relay activations.  I have a cat6 there with ethernet.  However, I need to connect the IP Camera to the cable too. And there isn't room for a switch (and its 220V power adapter) in that housing.

That is, I have two devices needing ethernet - the camera and the pi.

Qs:  Is there a pi hardware configuration and software to make the pi act like a switch as well as run another program on it that can use the ethernet connection?

*To do the function of the switch and control, I will need the pi to have two ethernet ports and two relays.*

Comment: Edited question.  I realise that I will need additional hardware for the 2nd ethernet port and relays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a USB Ethernet adapter of course.

The best way is to create a bridge between `eth0` (on board) and `eth1` (USB). For this, you need to install `bridge-utils`.  The basic configuration will be something like:

```
brctl addbr br0
brctl setfd br0 0
brctl addif br0 eth0 eth1
ifconfig eth0 -arp promisc 0.0.0.0 up
ifconfig eth1 -arp promisc 0.0.0.0 up
```

but you may need to tweak a little to get it working the way that you want.

Note that Renkforce has a very small 3 port switch that is powered from USB.